# Mule - Stitching together XML after For Each & Message Enricher

Tags: mule, mule-el, dataweave

I'm calling a service that returns XML. I need to call the service for each event id (there are usually 2), and then stitch the 2 pieces of xml up into one result using dataweave.

My flow is putting the XML results in an Array as type: org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream.

I'm a bit confused as to how to output as XML. I've tried various transformers such as object to XML with no luck.

My current dataweave transformer outputs the xml results as strings without correct xml formatting, and attempting to access the xml nodes returns coercion type errors.

```
 Sample XML:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
 <xml>
     <result>
         <event>
             <id>1</id>
             <name>Item 1</name>
             <title>Item 1 title</title>
         </event>
     </result>
 </xml>




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
 <xml>
     <result>
         <event>
             <id>2</id>
             <name>Item 2</name>
             <title>Item 2 title</title>
         </event>
     </result>
 </xml>
```

Mule Flow:

```
    Mule Flow:
 <flow name="eventsFlow">
     <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/eventsTest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <set-variable variableName="event" value="#[{'1','2'}]" doc:name="Event ID's"/>
     <set-variable variableName="results" value="#[new java.util.ArrayList()]" doc:name="Results"/>
     <foreach collection="#[flowVars['event']]" doc:name="For Each">
         <enricher target="#[results.add($)]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
             <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api_xml/api_xml.php?function=get_personal_results&amp;event_id=#[flowVars.event]&amp;key=INSERT_KEY_HERE" method="GET" metadata:id="dfa451b2-1ad5-4b27-bed9-841e5d0995b8" doc:name="Result Request"/>
         </enricher>
     </foreach>
     <set-payload value="#[flowVars.results]" doc:name="Payload"/>
     <dw:transform-message metadata:id="3875f88d-e232-42e7-93c9-184baf7c216f" doc:name="Transform Message">
         <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[
 %dw 1.0
 %output application/xml
 ---
 xml: {
     (payload map {
         result: {
             event: $
         }
     }

             )
 }]]></dw:set-payload>
         </dw:transform-message>
     </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a:

```
<logger message="Payload: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO"/>
```

After your transform?

> I'm a bit confused as to how to output as XML.

Output where? To a log? To the caller? To the http request?

Comment: Hi Chad, the logger outputs: Payload: [org.glassfish.grizzly.uti
ls.BufferInputStream@2247874a, org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@30f
70c76]. Im just trying to output to the http request.